# Proper way for setting controllers in Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I cannot figure out which is the correct way of creating and using controllers. Let's imagine we have a controller with an index method for showing the database records and we have the following database structure:

|id|name|active|

So I want to display only the active records on the user side and all the records(both active & inactive) in the admin side. Logically for both actions, we would use the index method, right?  Shall we use the index method for the user side and create another method for the admin side or vice versa?
What is the most flexible solution so we can use Route::resource for both views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you have to implement a role system in your app and make 2 roles admin and user.
you can do the filter with many ways but the ones that i suggest are :

1. using a scope with your model that remove the inactif ones if the role is user.
2. using a trait with your model to return the right data for each role like 2 methods in the trait one for users and another for the admin.

this 2 ways do the filter on a model level and this is what i suggest, to have a good quality software. and also to not have a dirty and hard coded solution. because if this will change in the future you dont have to cross all the code you just edit the specific part.

You can check the laravel documentation to see details about the concepts.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

If you want keep on the same method add the restriction on database query only when the user is not an admin. For Example

```
$query = \App\Model::query();

if( !Auth::user()->isAdmin() )
{
    $query->where('active', true);
}

$records = $query->get();
```

Comment: For a cleaner syntax you can use `->when(/*condition*/, /*callback with filter*/)` to conditionally add a filter to a query. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#conditional-clauses